# Use FormPage to define a variable for later use

Tags: input

I want to be able to use `FormPage` (or `FormFunction`) to be able to create an Association List for later use in a notebook.  This should be very easy to do since `FormFunction`essentially creates this Association List automatically for use with Pure Functions in the code.

Something as simple as this creates the output I am after:

```
FormPage[{"First Name" -> "String", "Last Name" -> "String"}]
```

I would think that I could achieve what I was looking for with something like this:

```
FormPage[{"First Name" -> "String", "Last Name" -> "String"}, names =]
```

And the ideal output would simply be:

> names=<|"First Name"->"Bob","Last Name"->"Jones"|>

But, the lack of definition of the variable in the function definition argument of `FormPage` causes Mathematica to return an error without evaluating.

I did try the following hoping for a better result:

```
FormPage[{"First Name" -> "String", "Last Name" -> "String"}, names =#&]
```

But then when I call `names` I simply get an output of:

> #1 &

Surely I am missing something very simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FormPage[{"First Name" -> "String", "Last Name" -> "String"}, (names = #)&]
```

[image]

```
names
```

> <|"First Name" -> "qwerty", "Last Name" -> "asdfgh"|>

Comment: Awesome!  I knew I was missing something simple!